# Shell script batch removal of letters & numbers before certain symbol in reoccuring patterns

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, jpeg

How do I create a shell script to remove evertyhing before the first occuring "_" in  various JPGs as:

```
45-gawk-120_19529903_45369252_2048.jpg
orf-100-silt-turf_14858652_32781876_2048.jpg
krill-12_19518261_45533068_2045.jpg
```

so I get the following:

```
19529903_45369252_2048.jpg
14858652_32781876_2048.jpg
19518261_45533068_2045.jpg
```

(Not enough expertise writing own shell scripts so far)

Comment: [tag:windows] [tag:cmd] does not run [tag:shell] scripts, ([tag:sh]), it runs [tag:batch-file]s. Please [Edit] your question and tags to prevent misunderstandings, and targetting the wrong readership. Please also read through the topics within [ask], to better understand how this process works, and submit the code you have written yourself to achieve your goal. We are essentially here to help you to fix a specific issue with your submitted code, not to post our code according to your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

`cut -d_ -f2-` will do what you're asking for:

Example:

```
echo 45-gawk-120_19529903_45369252_2048.jpg | cut -d_ -f2-
echo orf-100-silt-turf_14858652_32781876_2048.jpg | cut -d_ -f2-
echo krill-12_19518261_45533068_2045.jpg | cut -d_ -f2-
```

Output:

```
19529903_45369252_2048.jpg
14858652_32781876_2048.jpg
19518261_45533068_2045.jpg
```